# From Moodle Auto Login on Another Site on Clicking a Link

Tags: php, moodle, autologin

When a student logs in Moodle, and clicks on a link (to an external site), I want him to login to that external site. How should I proceed with this. I have checked LTI compliance. But not sure, how it will work for another site. My code is based in PHP.